# is it possible to generate an exe file from jlink output?

Tags: javafx, jlink

**Environment:** Win10, jdk11, javafx11, maven, jlink, intellij

I built a modular javafx application and tried to deploy it using jlink and all things are going well. jlink creates a custom runtime image that contains all application needs to run without installing java in the host machine comes with a .bat file to launch the app, but what I need is an exe file to use it with a third party application like 'inno setup' to make a single .exe installer

Comment: Use `jpackage` in conjunction with `jlink` to build a native package with the custom runtime image bundled in it. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) has an entire “packaging” section.

Comment: You mention creating an installer file. Note that `jpackage` creates installer files. However, you can specify the type of output as `app-image`, which will only generate the application without wrapping it in an installer file. That may allow you to use a third-party tool to create the installer file. On Windows, for example, the app image will have an `exe` file that will launch the application (it's not an installer file). See the [user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/packaging-overview.html) for more information.

Comment: Also note that `jpackage` was added in Java 14 as a preview feature and then was standardized in Java 16.